# Do mechanical drain traps exist for retrofit on inaccessible plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain

I recently purchased a home that has a shower with no drain trap.  The home is built on a concrete slab.  I plan to gut and replace the shower (and break concrete/re-work plumbing) eventually.  However, I am curious if there is some sort of mechanical trap that could be used in the short-term?

I am thinking something that could just be temporarily placed inside the 2" drain pipe (like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-in-PVC-DWV-Closet-Flange-888-GPM/202274094) for repairing toilet flanges).  I am just trying to prevent the nasty smell/gasses that are coming up it (although it is just tied into a grey water line, not sewer).  We are hoping to continue using the shower even in the short-term before we can get it fixed correctly with a P-Trap.

Comment: Are you *sure* it has no trap? Someone screwed up royally if that's the case.  Could it be just dried out?

Comment: I suppose it is possible, but I have put a lot of water down it.  Even after putting water down it, if I turn the bathroom vent fan on there is breeze coming out of the drain.  I have not sent a camera down it (I don't have one), but looking with a flashlight I can a good distance down and there is no water pooling.

Comment: Did you do a product search? My five seconds yielded [this contraption](https://www.rectorseal.com/sureseal-eliminate-sewer-gas-evaporation/), for example.

Comment: [Here's another](https://www.amazon.com/Green-Drain-Inc-GD104-Waterless/dp/B00W2FUA92).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is a screw-down test plug:

[image: Test Plug]

[Test Plug](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-2-in-Gripper-Mechanical-Plastic-Test-Plug-33401/100346775)

These come in the major drain pipe sizes.  The rubber provides a good, temporary seal even if the surface is a bit irregular.  I'm used to seeing them with a metal top and bottom plate, but I guess they have moved on to plastic.

Comment: Thanks!  However, we were hoping that the shower could still be used.  It looks like this will also prevent water from going down.  I was hoping I could find something with a mechanical flapper of some sort to allow water down, but prevent smells from coming up.

Comment: Well, it has a simple thumb screw so it can be removed and replaced by anyone.  I'm not aware of a temporary one-way valve that would be flush with the shower floor, allow water down, and keep air from getting out.

Comment: This doesn't close the overflow passage, either.

Comment: @isherwood, I was assuming this was a floor drain for a shower only, not a tub/shower combo so no overflow.  Guess I could have asked for clarification.

Comment: Benefit of the doubt granted. :)